# What is the correct pronunciation of the word "solder"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I have been listening to a podcast where the host pronounces the word *solder* as "sodder" or "sod-der", even "saw-der". Same thing happened when the lecturer of one of my EE classes pronounced the word *solder*. As for me I pronounce the word *solder* as "sole-der" with a distinct L and a longish O.

Comment: /l/ and /r/ can both be so short before a stop consonant like /d/ that they practically disappear.  If you asked your lecturer, you might well find that he isn't consciously not pronouncing the /l/.

Comment: It shouldn't be sawder unless the speaker's from Bawston.

Comment: I don't know about elsewhere, but in SouthEast UK many if not most 'Estuary English' speakers articulate the 'l' as a 'w'. Including myself, but sometimes I think it's just lazy speech. I can put the 'l' in if I want to, but it's awkward, so I don't bother.

Comment: Much more important than how you pronounce solder is this: use leaded solder and be happy. 60/40 Tin/Lead. Friends don't let friends use lead-free junk. :)

Comment: In rural Northern Illinois, I learned to say /'sadər/, which I pronounced ['saɾɚ]. Having learned no English word _*sotter_ /'satər/ to contrast it with, I have no idea whether the [a] is long or not.

Answer (score 23):

Depends on if you are British or American. The British say sole-der. Americans say sod-der.

Comment: Never knew the Americans mispronounced that. ;-)  Why drop/corrupt the L?

Comment: @Orbling: Yes, why *would* we just *walk* right in here and start *talking* about making a silent L? It's *halfway* to madness to imagine we *could* do such a thing. ;=P

Comment: @Robusto: It's at least three quarters! H, P, K, yes - silent L? ;-)

Comment: @Robusto: Well done.

Comment: If you look at the etymology, the term comes from the 14th C English word *sawd* which in term comes from old French *soldure* from Latin *solidare*. The British may have *started* pronouncing the L under the influence of the French or Latin, whereas the Americans may have kept the 14th C pronunciation; I wouldn't be surprised if that pronunciation was still around in some British dialects in the 17th C. This actually seems more likely than that the Americans suddenly decided to drop the L for no good reason.

Comment: @Orbling, Just as guess, but from Wikipedia "from the Middle English word soudur." (sow-uh-dur?) and originally from Latin "solidare". So at some point, some smarty-pants went back and said, "actually..." No clue why they ended up on opposite sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I take the view that as England is the home of the language, other users should keep up with the changes. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling, [Where would we be without England as our guide?](http://www.wired.com/underwire/2011/03/omg-oxford-english-dictionary/)

Comment: @Sam: An acronym, now word, I use everyday, and by millions of others, so it should definitely be there.

Comment: @Orbling: sorry, but you're not going to get us to pay for upgrades to a perfectly good language.

Comment: @PeterShor: We are open source generally. ;-)

Comment: **Science!** (the 'l' is not only sient, it is impossible to see.)

Comment: There are actually two distinct British pronunciations, depending on accent: the vowel in the first syllable can be either long or short.

Comment: @Robusto...... but we do say "waLk", "taLk" and "haLf" in Australia and England!!! It's america that says "wark", "tark" and "haaf" which is the whole point the OP's question.

Comment: @PaulCarroll: They don't voice the /l/ in those words in England, though.

Comment: @Robusto yes they do mate, lived there for 5 years (ok there are many accents so I can't say it's ubiquitous)... it however very subtle (as in Oz), definitely not overly pronounced.

Comment: @PaulCarroll: I've been to England quite a bit, and I would have noticed. Also, [check this out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/talk).

Comment: Robusto The 'l' isn't silent in those words though, it's a vowel modifier. If you change 'walk' to 'wak' then it can no longer be pronounced with an elongated 'a' sound. Remove the 'l' from 'talking' and you get 'taking', remove it from 'would' and you get 'woud' (which at best guess would be more along the lines of 'wewd'). Arguably 'solder' is still an exception, and if it were following the rule it would be pronouced as 'souder', which is actually the modern French for solder. According to wiktionary the old French was 'solder' and it stems from the Latin 'solido'.

Answer (score 19):

This doesn't come from a dictionary, but I had a relative who spent most of his free designing clever circuits (from the 1920s onwards).

He always told me that the correct British pronunciation was "sodder", but that over the years it had started to be pronounced "solder" - which he believed was to avoid the embarrassment of a word that could be misinterpreted as being related to sodomy when speaking to people who didn't have a background in electronics (or pipework!).

He was a very respectable man with a very good knowledge of the English language and how it had evolved during the 20th century - and at least one of his electronicly minded friends also pronounced it "sodder".

Depending on your opinion of natural language, and if you should stick to more traditional, or modern, pronunciations either could therefore be correct.

Comment: Well the precursor OE *soudure* as pointed out by caxtontype certainly suggests your relative could actually have been correct. It is a *very* long time since the '**l**' entered the standard form, but maybe in some dialects this never happened until much much later, so there could still be a 'folk memory' of the original.

Comment: This is *almost* worth an upvote just for the nice story.

Comment: This is a weird answer. In England and the rest of the UK, I have only ever heard the *solder* pronunciation. Definitely not the "sodder" pronunciation.

Comment: @Tristanr I have to admit I have never heard anybody born after 1915 use this pronunciation (and this relative passed away several years ago, so I cannot follow this up any further).

However, I know that both he and at least one of his contemporaries used this pronunciation around me as a child.

Comment: I suppose if you were a circuit in a cartoon, ordering the electrician to “Solder me!” could be somewhat misleading…

Comment: This Independent article says that supposedly, not pronouncing an /l/ in "solder" was a mark of "U" English at one point in history: http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/a-u-and-non-u-exchange-in-1956-alan-ross-defined-the-language-that-marked-a-man-above-or-below-1420569.html

Answer (score 14):

The OED gives two pronunciations: **|ˈsɒldə(r)|** and **|ˈsəʊdə(r)|**

On [WordReference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/), the latter is given as U.S. pronunciation.

While on the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary they are both given as BrE, while for AmE we have a new one: **|ˈsɑːdər|**. [Here](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/solder) you can check them all out personally, audio included.

Comment: Nicely found. But they don't give *my* pronunciation! And to be honest I can barely even *hear* a difference between OALD's two British pronunciations, let alone reproduce them!

Comment: So maybe your pronunciation is more dialectal? I'm really asking, I don't know how much your accent is spread, but you said "Southeast UK" so I take it as a local accent? You're a native speaker right? You can't notice any difference at all? Sorry for the question-bombarding, questions came by themselves :D

Comment: *Estuary English* is a pretty common term round my neck of the woods. Obviously! Seriously, the stuff on Wikepedia looks right enough to me. There are millions of us, and we ain't all fick, like wot the tv sez. We just have cloth-ears for sounds we don't usually articulate ourselves. Don't most people?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Quite right, I can barely distinguish a difference.  It's like the *three* vs *free* difference ([th-fronting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting)), I *cannot* here the difference, let alone reproduce it.  I *think*, the London pronunciation is the **ˈsəʊldə(r)ˈ** type.

Comment: I can only hear it if I pay close attention with the volume fairly high. But so far as I'm concerned, lazy or not, *my* accent is effectively 'the London pronunciation' for lots of us - **sɒːdə** (if I've cut & pasted the symbols aright). We're definitely too lazy to articulate the final **r**!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Aye, I normally cope alright retaining the Rs, it's the central Ts and initial Hs that go for a burton.

Comment: @Orbling: Glottal stop (**ʔ**) sorts out my central Ts, but like you I have no truck with those orrible leading aitches (too lazy to even put the **'** in there!).

Comment: @Alenanno, is there anyone who *doesn't* have a "local accent"?

Comment: @Peter Taylor: If I can be pedantic, yes, there is. But you misunderstood what I said :D I meant that since his was the Sussex accent, it couldn't be taken as the "example" for standard English pronunciation in UK. Then he said it was the same as London pronunciation and the "side-discussion" stopped there. :D

Answer (score 8):

Whether or not to vocalize the 'l' in 'solder' seems to be a geographical issue.

Lionel Deimel has a nice article on [words with silent 'l's](http://www.deimel.org/language/l.htm).

Along with 'solder', he offers many other English words with silent 'l's, including:

- walk
- talk
- half
- calf
- yolk
- almond
- folk
- balk
- balm
- calm
- palm
- falcon
- salmon
- caulk
- haulm (which is a variation of halm)

Some readers will argue that many of the words in Deimel's list have vocalized 'l's, but, like 'solder', this is probably related to geography.

Comment: Of those words, I was taught to pronounce the 'l' in 'balm', 'calm', 'palm', and 'falcon'. Of those 4, the first 3 are much closer to being a separate sound made up of a blended 'lm' (and it feels that way in my mouth, too), whereas 'falcon' has a clearly articulated 'l' in the same way that 'light' has a clearly articulated 'l'. Edit: rural Saskatchewan, Canada.

Comment: The only words there that the 'L' is at all compressed in, in my experience, are the two *-alf* words, though only in certain localities.

Comment: `falcon` with a silent *l* ? Does it rhyme with `bacon`?  I have pronounced the *l* in `caulk` ever since an unfortunate incident helping my sister-in-law tile a bathroom.

Comment: Yea, I find that list a little liberal as well.

Comment: Heh, some of those are silent for me, some aren't. Some are intermediate - falcon has an 'l' somewhere between that in "ball" and "almond" for me.

Comment: The only one I pronounce the 'l' in is falcon, which (like solder) is another case where the 'l' was interpolated from Latin, but here I believe the American pronunciation almost always has the 'l', while it seems that the 'l'-less pronunciation survives in the U.K.

Comment: In the UK, the letter 'l' is pronounced. The letter 'o' is pronounced in a way that Americans and Canadians can't pronounce. The nearest North American equivalent pronunciation would be the "aaa" sound.

Comment: I would agree with everything in this list (haven't looked at the full list but the ones listed here). I pronounce ‘falcon’ and ‘falconry’ as ‘faucon(ry)’.

Comment: As a non-english native speaker, another word I was taught to pronounce without L was `chalk`

Comment: Whether or not those l's are silent depends very much on accent and British and American people will disagree on many of them. And you don't actually answer the question...

Answer (score 6):

In my accent (inland Cascadian English, in the northwestern United States), we say [sɑɾɚ], as "saw-der," to rhyme with "water." It looks like it should be pronounced [sɔldɚ] or similar, as "sole-der," to rhyme with "colder," and it may be pronounced that way elsewhere.

And, yes, to make that perfectly clear: **in my accent, *solder* rhymes with *water*.** That seems so bizarre now that I really think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Merriam Webster dictionary gives:

Middle English soudure, from Anglo-French, from souder to solder, from Latin solidare to make solid, from solidus solid
First Known Use: 14th century

Comment: It's nice to see my dropping the '**l**' has a long & noble history going back a millenium or more! I bet the Romans thought we were ignorant southerners because we couldn't or wouldn't pronounce it anything like them!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - been trying to find a way to write the mid Scottish pronunciation, where the L is very strong! So much that the final er almost vanishes by comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard both soul-der and sol-der with a long and short 'o', sometimes the 'o' is so short you lose the 'l'

In BE the long 'o' is possibly more common

Comment: In the UK, the 'l' in *solder* is normally pronounced. You made a good point about the letter 'o'. That's true.

Answer (score 1):

Not one of these words has a truly silent 'l' in all cases the 'l' works as a modifier.

- wak
- tak
- haf
- caf
- yok
- amond
- fok
- bak
- bam
- cam
- pam
- facon
- samon
- cauk
- haum

Now Consider Solder.

- Soder

It is a unique case.

It seems that the 'l' is [only silent in the US](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solder#Pronunciation) not in the rest of world.

Comment: The yank pronunciation of solder is due, no doubt, to the influence of froggy N. American fur trappers who used **soudure** to fix their snares 'n traps.

Comment: `cam foks bam a pam`. Just terrible. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

After living in the US for 25 years, I can't think of any word that is harder to get into my transatlantic brogue than "sodder". I actually do prefer the subtler sound of the American form — my ear appreciates it, but I hesitate to imitate it. I also sign on to the notion that it's one of the many, many words whose original meaning or pronunciation the wayward British have forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

"The rest of the world" of course consists solely of Great Britain itself, and countries which were once colonies of Great Britain.  Of course, the U.S. was too; but we severed most of our ties with the mother country earlier than most of the others, at a time when the language was still very much in flux.

So to say "the rest of the world" when the rest of the world has been highly influenced by a single country, means very little.  As a matter of mere numbers, most native English speakers are actually American in any case.

Now, if you want to say that American English has changed more in the last few hundred years than British English, I think you'd be hard pressed to prove that.  For example, though we get made fun of for NOT pronouncing the "h" in "herb", according to the OED nobody did until the 19th century.  In fact, the word was earlier (ME) spelled as "erb" or "erbe".  It isn't that Americans stopped pronouncing an "h" that everyone else did, but that the British started pronouncing it.

In any case, pick up any of the works of Shakespeare, or a copy of the King James version of the Bible.  You will find that English as spoken has changed quite a bit since then.  (And you won't even actually be seeing the King James Bible in its 1611 form; it's been edited several times since then, but the edits didn't necessarily have much fanfare.  Most KJVs actually follow a 19th century edit.)

The point is, the language has changed a lot in the last 400 years -- on both sides of the Atlantic.  We didn't invent the pronunciation "sodder", even if we're not the only ones who still use it.

Comment: Please understand that this is not a discussion forum. Please only answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Australia, obviously being originally a British colony, we pronounce it “Sole-der”, as in *colder*. To me *dodder* *sodder* just make me think of to sodomise something, which is obviously not good. So it makes me cringe every time I hear an American pronounce it that way.

To say that because we don't pronounce the *l* in words like *walk* and *talk* means we don't in *solder*, *is* silly. We pronounce the *l* in *cold* and in *sold* and even *mould*.

To me *solder* sounds like it comes from the word *solid* in someway and I have nothing to back that up with, but that is what happens to *solder*, it starts as solid and ends up as a solid. You pronounce the *l* in *solid* right?

Anyway, like I said, it just makes more sense to me.

Comment: I cringe whenever I see an Australian forget to capitalize *British* or *American*. I cringe whenever I see an Australian forget that *sodomize* derives from the Biblical city of *Sodom* and therefore misspell it. I cringe whenever I see an Australian forget that America was as much of a British colony as Australia was. I cringe whenever I see an Australian post a rant as though it were an answer.

Comment: Good points, Jared. To say that because we don't pronounce the *l* in words like *walk* and *talk* means we don't in *solder*, seems only to apply to American English.

Comment: As an Australian, every second word I utter seems to be "bugger", but "sodder" is too close to "sod off" or "you sods" and is not polite. How did Celica become "silly car" rather than "sleeker"? Oregano I can live with. I imagine Quebec and French Polynesia have similar issues...