# Why is the word "folks" pronounced [foʊks]?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, consonants, silent-letters

Why is the word *folks* sound like it’s pronounced [foʊks] rather than [fɔɫks]? It’s as though people are thinking it’s spelled *fokes*.

Comment: This may be a regional variable. The "l" may still be pronounced at least to some degree in parts of the Anglosphere. There may also be some variation in the way the vowel is rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of historical loss/vocalization of the sound /l/ in certain contexts. As Max Williams mentioned, we also see this loss in *-alk* words like *walk, talk, chalk, balk, stalk.* Some American English speakers have restored the /l/ in some of these words as well as some other words that traditionally have silent /l/ (like the *-alm* set). (I don't know if any speakers have retained the /l/ via continuous transmission from some accent that didn't have this sound change.)

The word *yolk* shows the same phenomenon.

The pronunciation of "olk" in non-Germanic words, and proper names is somewhat variable. The Oxford English Dictionary gives pronunciations with /l/ for "polka" in both British English and American English (although they usually have different vowel qualities), as well as an l-less pronunciation for American English speakers only.

Comment: Did we restore the /l/, or did some dialects just never stop pronouncing it? I don't know.

Comment: @PeterShor: Well, I don't know for sure either, but that is my impression. It at least seems like the use of /l/ in "alm" words has become more frequent recently in American English.

Comment: Yes, it's become more frequent. But a few people were pronouncing the /l/ 100 years ago. I don't know about 200 years ago.

Comment: Do Brits also pronounce the l in "polka dots"?

Comment: Yes, they generally do, @bof. On the other hand I have noticed that many Americans do not pronounce the 'l' in _solder_.

Comment: @ColinFine: There is a question about that one: [What is the correct pronunciation of the word "solder"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/)

Answer (score 2):

The l is silent.  I don't think I've ever heard anyone pronounce the "l", anyway.  See also *walk, talk, chalk, stalk, half, calf, could, should, would* and probably many more.

As to "why do we have these silent letters?" - the language changes all the time, and pronunciation changes faster than spelling.  It's inconsistent.

Comment: Another pair like that is *palm* and *almond*, where some people have an [ɑɫ], some have [ɔɫ], and still others have just [ɔ].

Answer (score 2):

For comparison, phonemically *vault* is /vɔlt/, *wolf* is /wʊlf/, and *bolt* is /bolt/, but how words like those actually get pronounced varies a great deal.

One thing that’s common is for /l/ in the coda to becomes not merely [ɫ] but all the way to [w], which creates a phonetic (but not phonemic) diphthong. That’s what’s happening here.